# How to update a .txt file using PHP

Tags: php

My colleague and I are working on a chat application for a small Flash based game. We would like to keep our chat file as small as possible by automatically deleting old text after the file has reached a certain limit. Say the file exceeds 50 lines, we would like to delete the existing information and begin again at line 1. Is this possible?

```
<?php

$file = "saved.txt";
$edited_text = $_POST['new_text'];

$open = fopen($file, "a+");
fwrite($open, "\n" . $edited_text);
fclose($open);

?>
```

Comment: Use the [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function for reading line-wise, and [`count()`](http://php.net/count) or [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) for trimming to 50 lines. And don't forget [file locking](http://php.net/flock).

Comment: Is there a special requirement to use a textfile? A file based database like splite might be more effective and easier to handle.

Comment: You'll have to check the number of lines when it reaches 50 instead of appending, overwrite the file.

Comment: I've to agree with @Rangad here. A small SQLite database would definitely fit the use scenario here and I'd suggest using that opposed to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Basically something like this:

```
$lines = file('saved.txt');
$lines[] = 'new line of text';
array_unshift($lines); // remove first array element
file_put_contents('saved.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

1. Read the file into an array, one line per array element
2. Append your new line(s) of text
3. Remove as many lines from the start of the array as necessary
4. dump array back out to file as text.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
// Read entire file
$lines = file_get_contents('saved.txt');
// Add what you want to the beginning of array
array_unshift($lines, 'new line of text');
// Keep first 50 items
$lines = array_splice($lines, 0, 50);
// Write them back
file_put_contents('saved.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Will always keep the first 50 elements intact (which includes messages from new to old).